# PHPUnit Test on Laravel 5.8 fails

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I'm working in laravel 5.8 project.

```
127.0.0.1/test_project/public/index.php.
```

I'm getting 404 response. How do I fix this?

I have a test:

Route:

```
Route::apiResource('Vehicle.source', 'API\VehicleController');
```

API Call:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test_project/public/index.php/api/Vehicle/22222/source/DB

API Response:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "identifier": "22222",
            "make": "wwwww",
            "model": "3333",
            "year": 44445,
            "created_at": "2019-08-02 07:02:51",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-02 07:02:51"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "identifier": "22222",
            "make": "wwwww",
            "model": "3333",
            "year": 44445,
            "created_at": "2019-08-02 07:21:01",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-02 07:21:01"
        }
    ],
    "status": 500
}

<?php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class VehicleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetVehicleFromDB() 
    {
        $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/Vehicle/22222/DB');  
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertJson(['message' => "Vehicle Retrived!"]);
    }
}
?>
```

Error message is like below:

> 1) Tests\Unit\VehicleTest::testGetVehicleFromDB Expected status code
>   200 but received 404. Failed asserting that false is true.
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fixico_test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:151
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fixico_test\tests\Unit\VehicleTest.php:25
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.

Comment: That's not a unit test btw

Comment: You are getting a 404 meaning that you are not providing the right url. This part --> `/public/index.php` seems weird to be honest.